# Edit .NET assembly and recompile

Tags: .net, refactoring, .net-assembly, decompiler

I'm in a really bad situation. I lost my source code and my customer needs to change a little bit in the application. Think of edit an assembly for an example: Test.dll then add a code line and finally recompile it

So my question is:
- Is it possible to do that?
- If it's possible, what is the good tool to edit an assembly and then recompile it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, get [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), it has the ability to save an assembly to disk with a .csproj and everything. This makes it easy to open in Visual Studio and recompile.

ILSpy is free and open source.

[image: Save Code]

Answer (score 25):

Exporting & recompiling might not be possible for large applications with many assembies, so I'd suggest a different approach:

The most comfortable way to go might be to use [Reflexil](http://reflexil.net/) in combination with [.NET Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) (not free) or [JustDecompile from Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) (very free). I did this a few times and had the best result with JustDecompile - even if I'd prefer [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) over JustDecompile at any other time.

**"Now, how"? you might ask:** [Here's a small tutorial from the guys at Telerik.](http://www.telerik.com/docs/default-source/documents/justdecompile/justdecompile-reflexil-faq.pdf?sfvrsn=4)

(look at the topic *"How can I inject C# code in an assembly?"*)

---

## UPDATE

#### You should definitely look at the new kid on the block: [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy)

Answer (score 6):

[Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) is the most well known tool for disassembling .net Executables. Another tool is [Dis#](http://www.netdecompiler.com/).